# SharePoint List Calculated column to calulate Totals

Tags: calculated-column

I could import the excel data shown here to a SharePoint list 2010.I imported all the columns. Let's say I have two columns. Name and Value.
For Value column, I have numeric type. I need to calculate Score for Value column, which can be calculated(In EXCEL) as
(COUNTA(Value)/Total items in the sheet)*100

How do I calculate this value in SharePoint 2010 list? I tried adding a calculated field but it doesn't allow to use any functions such as COUNT, SUM, AVG etc. It only allows to calculate the values based on other column values.

Can you first create a form out of the list and add all the required fields in the form and for each form field, calculate the formula?

Help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Calculated columns will only work for values in the current item (row) and will not span across the entire list. For displaying a total across multiple items you will need to use a view.

Using the standard view editor within SharePoint you can only do basic SUMs or COUNTs (Under the Totals section of the View editor). To do your more complex calculation you will need to use SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Thanks theChrisKent. I agree with you on first statement. I also found that I could do basic COUNTs and SUM under Totals section of the View Editor.I need to do lil complex calculation using SPD. Any idea on where to start from?

Comment: @Nemo Sounds like a new question. ;)

Comment: @KitMenke, yes a new question. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: @Nemo - I think Kit meant that you should ask this is a totally new question rather than putting it on the end of this question.